# Questions about actionBar android

Tags: java, android, image, sdk, android-actionbar

1. How add image in action bar? Example: I have products that can be added to the cart. Shopping image is in Action Bar. If i add 2 products, in Shopping image display little 2. If i press Shopping image i move on Shopping activity.
2. How display another image menu in action bar? Example: I have 3 activity, in one  activity display menu image car in action bar, in two activity display menu apple in action bar, it three display menu image dog action bar.
3. How display only two images in action bar, one image in left corner, two image in right corner? Example: I have menu image edit and image menu exit in action bar. Edit image in left corner, exit image in right corner.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets showing what you have already tried?

Comment: What you ask is largely covered in lots of tutorials...

Comment: From your description, it's not clear what you have tried, so it is harder for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use customView for actionbar , So you can do anything you want.

http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android